# How can I get email of the last user who modified each cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Trying to add a 'rolling' note of changes at each cell, including user email, time, old and new values, so I wrote the below script:

```js
/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();

  // Get the email address of the person running the script.
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  Logger.log("data changed");
  range.setNote(range.getNotes().concat('Last modified at: ' + new Date() + ' by: ' + email + ' from: ' + String(e.oldValue) + ' to: ' + range.getValue() + "\n"));
}
```

I'd the below notes, that are not as I expect:

1. User email not displaying at all,
2. If I made copy/paste of multiple cells, then old value appear as undefined, and new value for all cells shows only the new value of the first cell.

My sheet can be opened [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnR0ltbFo81iiH22Wu39vHA9xhunu4fVml7sbfMWA70/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Doesn't this information  already present in sheets for every cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info that you are adding is already automatically recorded and available by right clicking on a cell and selecting the corresponding menu item, anyway, the simple on edit trigger is very limited compared with the installable on edit trigger but the `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` only returns an email if the script is ran by using G Suite accounts or by the owner of the spreadsheet / script or the user created the installable on edit trigger that called the script. Somehow this is already documented in the official docs.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser

Related

- [Determine current user in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12300777/1595451) (oldest +7 at this time with an answer with +12)
- [Google Spreadsheets: Can't Fetch User Email via Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22313868/1595451)
- [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() returns no Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48183463/1595451)
- [Set Permission for getEmail to Work for Users on Same G Suite Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58664414/1595451)